# Using netcat with -p option

Tags: linux, networking, netcat

I used netcat in the following way

```
nc -l 3333    //for server

nc 127.0.0.1 3333  // for client
```

With this I am able to use it as a two way chatting system.

My question is, then why is there another option

> -p ( -p source_port Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability.)

It works with -p option too. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

A TCP connection consists of two TCP endpoints, each consisting of an IP address and a TCP port. The client usually chooses a random port, although you can force `netstat` to use a given port using the `-p` option.

Try:

```
adi@laps:~$ nc -l 3333 -p 4444
nc: cannot use -p and -l
adi@laps:~$ nc -l 3333 &
[1] 6025
adi@laps:~$ nc localhost 3333 -p 3333
nc: bind failed: Address already in use
```

Comment: Oh okay.. So we can specify the client to use a specific port when sending packets?  so there is no use for the server with the -p option?

Comment: @DesirePRG the client uses that port both for sending and receiving data. And the server's port in a connection with a client is not actually 3333: that is the listening port, the server gets a different port when accepting a connection.