# Why won't my bash script run correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I have a simple script, that works fine in the terminal, but not in init.d scripts or crontab. I'm working on a raspberry pi.

Is there a rule to writing scripts that run in the background?

This is my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while true; do echo "ALIVE" | sudo nc -l -p 80; done
```

Comment: When you run that script you probably had to input the password on the `sudo` call. How do you do that in crontab or init.d?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using netcat with -p option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196438/using-netcat-with-p-option)

Comment: @alfasin That's not a valid duplicate.

Comment: @tripleee you might be right, but unfortunately, I can't revert my vote.

Comment: Sure you can.  Click on "close" again and select the "revert" option near the bottom.  Either way, maybe remove the public "possible duplicate" comment.

Comment: Two things :  (1) when you sudo as yourself into root you bring with you your id's environment ... assure you put into root's .bashrc or somehow source  environment settings like PATH as your own id  (2) no need to sudo if is already executed as root

Answer (score 1):

1. Cron scripts defined in `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d` or via
   `crontab -e` may run as a **user** other than `root`. All permissions
   (e.g. on logfiles) and authorization information (in your case `sudoers`) must be set 
   accordingly.
2. If they do not contain a [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line, cron scripts may run in a different **shell**, depending on the user the script is running as (see the shell set in `/etc/passwd`). The shell can also be overridden via `SHELL` variable in a crontab. This is not relevant for the OP's script.
3. The shell running `init.d` and `cron` scripts may be using a different
   **environment**. Most notably the `PATH` may be different, so it is recommended to use absolute paths only or set the `PATH` as needed.

Comment: Regarding #2, the OP's script has the bash shebang at the top of the script, it's doubtful the default shell will run the script. That would break all sorts of things, like binary executables. Is that actually an issue?

Comment: @piojo Of course you are right. Most cron and init.d scripts I have seen do have the shebang line, and it has priority when a script is executed. However the shebang is not required, so for general debugging, this should be considered. I will edit my answer to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

1. The user running the script must be able to sudo. Configure this with the `visudo` command.
2. You should check for output/errors. You can do that by changing it to:

   `while true; do echo "ALIVE" | sudo nc -l -p 80 &>/var/log/netcat-test.log; done`

Note that you should write the log to a place where that user definitely has access, and a directory that already exists. But this will trash your disk, due to writing lots and lots of logs. I suggest adding a delay:

```
 while true; do echo "ALIVE" | sudo nc -l -p 80 &>>/var/log/netcat-test.log; sleep 30; done
```

3. You should check that the script is started at all. Add `echo Script started >> the-log-file; date >> the-log-file`. If the script is not starting, make sure it is marked as executable. If the script IS starting, make sure the script is not causing the system to crash--does the system need this script to return? Because it is not currently a background daemon. It does not ever finish, nor does it return control to the shell. Try replacing `while true` with `for count in 1 2` for testing, to execute just twice.

Comment: If you are running out of `init.d` you are already `root` and don't need `sudo`.

Comment: @tripleee The OP ran it from "init.d or crontab". That means it's necessary to cover all the bases, IMO.